# Pass an image file to AWS lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I would like to know if there is a way to pass an image file from the client and send it to AWS lambda function. I ask this because I have to save the image file in a S3 bucket but I want to rename and compress the file in the lambda function before uploading it. If it's not possible give me your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. Save the image (PutObject) in a S3 bucket. It is called Push Model where a `PutObject` in S3 triggers a lambda execution. The S3 object name (key) is passed to the lambda function. The lambda when invoked, downloads the image fie, resizes it and uploads the resized image to a different bucket in S3.

AWS has detailed documentation and example for your use case. Check [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) and [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)